# Verify File Uploaded to Rackspace Cloud Files

Tags: php, rackspace-cloud, cloudfiles

I'm using the direct form post to Rackspace Cloud Files to upload files, documented [here](http://docs.rackspace.com/files/api/v1/cf-devguide/content/Create_the_Form-d1a777.html).

In the form, I've included the optional "redirect" parameter with a value of "status.php"

If a file is successfully uploaded, it will append: `?status=201&message=`

So at the end of a successful file upload, the user is taken to: `status.php?status=201&message=`

status.php then retrieves the querystring parameters. If status is 201, the user is redirected forward. Otherwise, the user is redirected back to the upload.

All of that is working fine.

However, on rare occasion, the user will complete the entire process (indicating that he received a 201 status), but the file never makes it to Cloudfiles.

Has anyone heard of anything like that happening?

If the 201 status is unreliable, what's the best way to verify that the file actually exists before redirecting the user forward?

Thanks!

Comment: try to download the file? presumably if the upload failed, you'd get a 404 at that point.

Comment: Hmmm... simple, but effective. Using `get_headers()` on the file and checking for a 200 response does the trick nicely. Thanks for the idea!